# Cassandra add nodes and modify snitch in existing cluster

Tags: cassandra

Currently we have a 3 node Cassandra cluster with `SimpleSnitch` and keyspaces with `SimpleStrategy` and RF=1 
and now, we want to add 3 nodes in our cluster, and they located in the same DC but on different Physical racks. this nodes are presented and cassandra successfully installed on it, but I'm never start them
so my plan is

1. change configs in `/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml` add/change the following

```
auto_bootstrap: true
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

2. in  `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc` `dc=datacenter1` and  `rack=rack1{2,3}`
3. then restart old cluster (one by one) using `nodetool drain` && `systemctl restart cassandra`
4. start new 3 nodes with right settings (`GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` and right rack)
5. check the `nodetool describecluster` and `nodetool status`
6. ALTER user and system keyspaces (`system_auth`, `system_traces`, and `system_distributed`) change the Strategy and RF
7. `nodetool repair -pr` on every node in the cluster
8. `nodetool cleanup` on every node (except the last node)

is my plan correct? i've played with my dev cassandra cluster and all is ok